# How to add custom logrotate configuration files to Ubuntu core?

Tags: ubuntu-core, logrotate

Is there a way to add custom `logrotate` configuration files to Ubuntu core? `/etc/logrotate.d` is not writable. Should `/writable/system-data/etc/logrotate.d` be sourced? It doesn't seem to work and also is not referenced in the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because `/etc/logrotate.d` is a directory and not a writable file. You can add a file under `/etc/logrotate.d/` for your specific application, or edit one of the existing default ones.

Here is what my system has by default:

```
$ ls /etc/logrotate.d/
apache2  consolekit  jockey-common  rsyslog            unattended-upgrades
apport   cups        pm-utils       speech-dispatcher  upstart
apt      dpkg        ppp            ufw
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Grayson - thank you for the follow up. It turns out for Ubuntu Core that /etc/logrotate.d is not writable. It sounds like 3rd-party scripts are not supported. Same issue with cron. I happen to be using docker so I created a docker container that periodically calls logrotate on my script. A bit of a hack but with restart: always it seems reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I came up with assuming a docker environment. I'd appreciate hearing if someone has a better answer:

It turns out for Ubuntu Core that /etc/logrotate.d is not writable. It sounds like 3rd-party scripts are not supported for logrotate. Same issue with cron.

I happen to be using docker so I created a docker container that periodically calls logrotate on my script. A bit of a hack but with "restart: always" it seems reliable.